# Trying to map data through props to React Bootstrap Accordion - data not displaying?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-props, array.prototype.map

I am trying to map data from my data file through props into my React-Bootstrap Accordion component. The method I am using will change as I progress as I know the formatting wont be exactly how I want it moving forward.

However I cant actually visualise or work out how to get structure right as I can't even see the data or the Accordion component displaying but I get no errors in the console.

Essentially I want to be able to use the map function to create all the react-bootstrap accordion components with the data from the props.

Code is below please let me know if any more is needed.

Menu.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Accordion, Button, Card, Jumbotron, Table } from "react-bootstrap";

function Menu(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Accordion>
        <Card>
          <Card.Header>
            <Accordion.Toggle as={Button} variant="link" eventKey="0">
              {props.header}
            </Accordion.Toggle>
          </Card.Header>
          <Accordion.Collapse eventKey="0">
            <Card.Body>
              {props.body}{" "}
              <Button variant="light" className="menu-basket-btn">
                <i class="fas fa-shopping-basket"></i>
              </Button>
            </Card.Body>
          </Accordion.Collapse>
        </Card>
      </Accordion>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Menu;
```

Home.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Jumbotron } from "react-bootstrap";
import Menu from "../Components/MenuFolder/Menu";

import data from "../Components/MenuFolder/MenuData";

const menuCreator = (item) => {
  <Menu 
    key={item.id} 
    header={item.header} 
    body={item.body} />;
};

function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="home-page">
      <div className="home-jumbotron">
        <Jumbotron>
          <h1>Fresh Asian Cuisine straight to your door!</h1>
          <p>Order direct from our website for the best deals and prices!</p>
        </Jumbotron>
      </div>
      <div className="menu-section">
        <section className="starters">
          <div>
            <h1 className="title">Starters</h1>
            {data.map(menuCreator)}
          </div>
        </section>
        <section className="mains">
          <h1 className="title">Mains</h1>
          <div></div>
        </section>
        <section className="desserts">
          <h1 className="title">Desserts</h1>
        </section>
        <section className="sundries">
          <h1 className="title">Rice</h1>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

MenuData.js

```
const data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        header: "Meat Dumplings",
        body: "6pc's - £4.99",
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        header: "Veggie Dumplings",
        body: "6pc's - £3.99",
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        header: "Duck Spring Rolls",
        body: "4pc's - £4.29"
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        header: "Veggie Spring Rolls",
        body: "4pc's - £3.79",
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        header: "Green Thai Curry",
        body: "£9.99"
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        header: "Red Thai Curry",
        body: "£9.99",
    },
    {
        id: 6,
        header: "Pad Thai",
        body: "£12.99"
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        header: "Japanese Curry",
        body: "£10.99"
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        header: "Spicy Sichuan Tofu Noodles",
        body: "£8.99"
    },
    {
        id: 9,
        header: "Tonkotsu Ramen",
        body: "£12.99"
    },
    {
        id: 10,
        header: "Spicy Miso Noodles",
        body: "£7.99"
    },
    {
        id: 11,
        header: "Oyaka Don",
        body: "£8.99"
    },
    {
        id: 12,
        header: "Matcha Brownies",
        body: "£4.99"
    },
    {
        id: 13,
        header: "Salted Caramel Brownies",
        body: "£3.99"
    },
    {
        id: 14,
        header: "Jasmine Rice",
        body: "£2.99"
    },
    {
        id: 15,
        header: "Sticky Japanese Rice",
        body: "£3.99"
    },
    {
        id: 16,
        header: "Basmati Rice",
        body: "£1.99"
    },
    {
        id: 17,
        header: "Egg Fried Rice"
    },
]

export default data;
```

Comment: I have added a solution. Please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few issues in your code.

**1.** Import bootstrap css or use bootstrap cdn(more you can read [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction))

```
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
```

**2.** You are not `returning` Menu component. It would be like this:

```
const menuCreator = (item) => {
  return <Menu key={item.id} header={item.header} body={item.body} />;
};
```

Here is complete working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-cloud-10u5z?file=/src/App.js:2042-2147

Comment: Thanks mate really appreciate you taking the time to do this! in regards to first point I am already importing the bootstrap css in my app.js!